# How to prove the following double integral is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-analysis, positive-definite

Let $\delta_{\min} (\cdot)$ and $\delta_{\max}(\cdot)$ stand for the smallest and largest eigen-values of a matrix.

Given matrix $A(w)$ and $B(w_1, w_2)$ and
$$0 < c_1 \leq \delta_{\min}(A(w)) \leq \delta_{\max}(A(w)) \leq c_2 < \infty,$$
$$\delta_{\min}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}B(w_1, w_2) \: dw_1 \, dw_2\right) \geq \xi_1 > 0,$$
$$\delta_{\max}\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi B(w_1, w_2) \: dw_1 \, dw_2\right) \leq \xi_2 < \infty.$$

Prove the following is positive definite.
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi A(w_1)B(w_1, w_2)A^T(w_2)\:dw_1 \, dw_2$$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks implausible. Are you sure that it's true? Are there any missing conditions?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  The final displayed double integral is a real number, right?  Are you asking if it is positive?  Or are $A$ and  $B$  matrix-valued functions?

Comment: Hi @kimchilover,   and  are matrix-valued functions. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi @user1551, thanks for your reply. I am not sure if it's true. I should have changed the problem to an open-ended question stead of a proof problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it. It is false. Let $a>0$ and consider the step functions
\begin{aligned}
A(t)&=\begin{cases}aI&\text{if }\ 0<t\le\pi,\\ I&\text{if }\ -\pi\le t\le0,\end{cases}\\
B(s,t)&=\begin{cases}-I&\text{if }\ (s,t)\in(0,\pi]^2,\\ I&\text{if }\ (s,t)\in[-\pi,\pi]^2\setminus(0,\pi]^2.\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
Then $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi B(s,t)\,ds\,dt=2\pi^2I$ is positive definite, but $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi A(t)B(s,t)A(t)^\top\,ds\,dt=(3-a^2)\pi^2I$ is negative definite when $a$ is large. You can also get a counterexample with smooth functions by slightly modifying $A$ and $B$ in the above.